# How to enable @src in npm package require statements

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using the npm ask-cli which uses require statements that include @src instead of direct paths using ../

module-alias is rejecting these paths

What's the best solution or utility to help recognize this type of path?

ex:

```
const CONSTANTS = require('@src/utils/constants');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package for create directory aliasing
https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

Comment: So if I enable module-alias in my package any other packages that use module-aliasing will work?